# simple input. program crashes

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(){        
    char *command="0";

    do {   
      printf("[A]dd, [P]rint, [Q]uit\n");
      scanf("%s", command);

    while (strcmp(command, "a") != 0 && strcmp(command, "A") != 0 && strcmp(command, "p") != 0 && strcmp(command, "P") != 0){
        printf("Invalid input. Please enter one of the commands listed above.\n");
        scanf("%s", command);
    }       

       if (strcmp(command, "a") == 0 || strcmp(command, "A") == 0){
           printf("You selected add.\n");
       }
       else if (strcmp(command, "p") == 0 || strcmp(command, "P") == 0){
           printf("You selected print.\n");
       }
    }while (strcmp(command, "q") != 0 && strcmp(command, "Q")!= 0);
    return 0;
}
```

I want the program to take in a letter from the user from one of the specified commands printed in the beginning. I want the program to exit if they enter q or Q. Took me a while simply to figure out how to do comparisons with strings for the loops and ifs. now when i run the program it crashes though. Looking for insight as to why its crashing.

Comment: May help to include the error message you're getting.

Comment: Where does it crash?  When you attach a debugger, what is the state of the program when it crashes?  Does the actual state match your expected state?

Comment: You can't change the contents of `command`: it points to a string literal. Try an array instead: `char command[] = "0";`. and be sure to limit the length of the string read with the scanf: `scanf("%1s")`

Comment: `scanf` is trying to write N bytes to the address pointed by `command`, which is a string-literal (read-only). You need to allocate enough memory to store these N bytes, or declare a fixed-length array of `chars`. Example: `char command[255]; scanf("%254s", command);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, make your buffer `command` into a regular array, and make it larger:

```
char command[256];
```

No need to initialize it, `scanf` will take care of that. Also, it won't affect the crashing but if you're only checking one letter, you can do it like this:

```
if command[0] != 'a' && command[0] != 'A' (etc.)
```

Note the single quotes: This is a character comparison.

Answer (score 0):

```
char *command="0";
scanf("%s", command);
```

you are writing to a string literal (of only 2 bytes) and string literals are not required to be modifiable.

Use something like this instead:

```
char command[256];
scanf("%s", command);
```

or better use `fgets` + `sscanf` to avoid potential buffer overflows.

Answer (score 0):

This is a pointer to read-only memory:

```
char *command="0";
```

Which means that this is wrong:

```
scanf("%s", command);
```

The "quick hack", which is the **bad way to do it**, is change the definition of command so it gets some read-write memory instead of read-only memory:

```
char command[256] = "0";
```

But this still puts you in grave danger of buffer overflow.  Don't use `scanf`.

The "better way" is to use `fgets` instead of `scanf`:

```
char command[256];
char *p;
p = fgets(command, sizeof(command), stdin);
if (!p) { handle error or EOF }
/* Don't forget that 'command' will probably have '\n' at the end,
   you will have to strip it off */
```

Comment: fgets and sccanf better in this case?

Comment: The format string passed to `scanf` allows limiting the string size. Example: "%255s"

Comment: @jweyrich: That's nice, but there are still 99 other reasons not to use `scanf`.

Comment: @TristanPearce: Avoid `sscanf`, `scanf`, `fscanf`, `vfscanf`, `vscanf`, and `vsscanf`.  Using them correctly is too tricky.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the first thing that pops out at me is that you're using `scanf` to read data into read-only memory -- i.e., a string constant. What happens when you try this is undefined, but a program  crash is likely. You need to allocate some read/write memory for `command`; declare it as, for example,

```
char command[10];
```